# Search based on zip code & radius

Tags: arcgis-online, circle, zip-codes

I am creating ArcGIS Online map and having a functionality to search Zip Code using the USA Zip Code 2014 pre-existing layer.
I further need to extend the functionality so that user can provide Zip Code & radius and can see visual representation of specified radius (from center of Zip Code)

Has anybody come across a similar scenario?

Comment: I think you would have to develop your own custom app using the JSAPI and then you could draw a graphic of a radius for your search results using the geometry service. In Online you can only show a buffer around features using the analysis tool and cannot leverage search. Maybe you might be able to find a WAB widget, check out the WAB group on GeoNet.

Comment: I totally agree with you - "In Online you can only show a buffer around features using the analysis tool and cannot leverage search".
As of now, I am using analysis tool only. and that is satisfying my requirement.
@RussRoberts - Please post your comment in the answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would have to develop your own custom app using the JSAPI and then you could draw a graphic of a radius for your search results using the geometry service. In Online you can only show a buffer around features using the analysis tool and cannot leverage search. Maybe you might be able to find a WAB widget, check out the WAB group on GeoNet.